# react transition group jumping slides

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, react-transition-group

between 2-nd and 3-d "page" jumping content i dont get what is the reason, cuz i've displayed it as an absolute
Here is sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-bhabha-d1dloy?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> page, the containing elements have class names of `page-left` and thus do not have `position: absolute` applied. You may have meant to apply `position: absolute` in your CSS:

```css
.page-left,
.page-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Instead of

```css
.page-right,
.page-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```